# 405 error on submitting a modelform using class based views

Tags: django, django-forms

I created a ModelForm which renders correctly and displayed but whenever i try to submit the form I get a 405 error and the page doesnt redirect to success page.

Ive gone through the django 2.2 documentation trying many different things but nothing seems to work

My code is configured as such the template:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'order_thanks' %}" 
method="post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Git my 
food!"></input>
```

The model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea, Select, 
CheckboxSelectMultiple, CheckboxSelectMultiple
from django import forms
BURGER_CHOICES = (("AFBB", "Aurion's Famous Beef Burger"), ("AIPB", 
"Aurion's Infamous Pork Burger"), ("AULB", "Aurion's Undiscovered Lamb 
Burger"), ("POG", "Pureed Otter Giblets"))
BUN_CHOICES = (("WHITE","White Bread"), ("RYE","Rye"), ("TPOODLE", 
"Teacup Poodles"), ("AFOSSIL","Ammonite Fossils"))
TOPPING_CHOICES = (("CHEESE", "Cheese"), ("LETTUCE", "Lettuce"), 
("TOMATOE", "Tomatoe"), ("ONION", "Onion"), ("WSHAVE", "Wood Shavings"))
SAUCES_CHOICES = (("OZTS", "Our Zesty Barbaque Sauce"), ("SEZBS", 
"Someone Elses Zesty Barbaque Sauce"), ("VS", "Varmint Squeezings"))
EXTRAS_CHOICES = (("P", "Pinapple"), ("SG", "Soylent Green"), ("SB", 
"Soylent Blue"), ("MWS", "More Wood Shavings"))

class Order(models.Model):
    burger = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=BURGER_CHOICES )
    bun = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=BUN_CHOICES)
    toppings = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=TOPPING_CHOICES)
    sauces = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=SAUCES_CHOICES)
    extras = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=EXTRAS_CHOICES)

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('burger', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.burger

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('order-thanks', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['toppings'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields.get(field_name)
            if field and isinstance(field , forms.TypedChoiceField):
                field.choices = field.choices[1:]
        self.fields['extras'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['burger', 'bun', 'toppings', 'sauces', 'extras']
```

the view:

```
class OrderView(CreateView, FormView):
    template_name = 'order_form.html'
    form_class = OrderForm
    success_url = 'order/thanks/'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def get(self, request):
        return Response(code=200)


class OrderThanksView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'order_thanks.html'
```

the urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('about/', views.AboutPage.as_view(),name='about'),
    path('order/', views.OrderView.as_view(),name='order'),
    path('order/thanks/', 
views.OrderThanksView.as_view(),name='order_thanks'),
]
```

Appologies I dont know how to display the code correctly in the post.

I added some debugging to the code and it turns out that the form is not valid so the redirect doesnt happen?

===============

I got the redirect working by making the multiple choice checkboxes as blank=True and setting the action in the template to "{% url 'order' %}

There seems to be an issue with the form when you select multiple options with eh check-boxes.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add your `OrderThanksView`

Comment: I added the OrderThanksView

Comment: In `OrderThanksView` view you extend `TemplateView` and in `TemplateView` POST method is not alowed. That's why you get 405. Mention what actually you want

Comment: I probably want to have a confirmation page list what you ordered etc...

Comment: Then change to this `action="{% url 'order' %}"`

Comment: I tried that just now and the page doesnt redirect. I also changed the view OrderThanksView to a ListView

Comment: thanks @shafik  appears that your fix works for the redirect